# CSS3 slider constructor with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do, to make it look like this

[image]

And this how it looked now

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nazaret2005/Zn2Lx/show/
or
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nazaret2005/aeJjL/show/

**The broblem is:** If i do with One **ul** and two or more **li** , the slide container go over the next li. (here the example http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nazaret2005/aeJjL/ )

And if i do with One **ul** and one **li** in all the information, have to make the gap between ul (here the example http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nazaret2005/Zn2Lx/ ).

How can i make it, like in screenshot ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... This is my approach, using the template you already built:

I move the class green from li to span

```
<li>
    <span class="OpenClose green">Novembr 2013 <cc>&#x25B2;</cc></span>
    <div class="orange">Some information here 2<a title="Download file 11" href="./download.php?file_id=11"></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

I removed the height of li

```
#download_j li {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
}
```

And i set the margin left of the inside div to 5px

```
#download_j li div {
    display: none;
    width: 705px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 7px 5px;
    background: #F7F5F2;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
}
```

You can check it out here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/aeJjL/7/

Answer (score 0):

css only solution

HTML

```
<section class="container">
    <div>
        <input id="nov13" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="nov13">Nov 2013</label>
        <article class="small">
            <p>other elements here </p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="dec13" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="dec13">Dec 2013</label>
        <article class="medium">
            <p>other elements here</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div><!--...--></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    font-family: calibri;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
}
.container label{
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #eee;
}
.container label:hover{
    background: #fff;
}
.container input:checked + label,
.container input:checked + label:hover{
    background: #c6e1ec;
    color: #3d7489;
}
.container label:hover:after,
.container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    right: 13px;
    top: 7px;
    background: transparent url(your_path/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center;  
}
.container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    background-image: url(your_path/arrow_up.png);
}
.container input{
    display: none;
}
.container article{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: 
        height 0.3s ease-in-out, 
        box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.container input:checked ~ article{
    transition: 
        height 0.5s ease-in-out,
}
.container article p{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.container input:checked ~ article.small{
    height: 140px;
}
.container input:checked ~ article.medium{
    height: 180px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4zL/)